# how to use infopath 2013 file attachment control

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, infopath, sharepoint-workflow, infopath-forms-services

I have created a form template in infopath 2013  which has a 'file attachment control'. This form needs to be published in sharepoint 2013. When I promote the file attachment fields I get this error 'The selected filed cannot be promoted becasuse its data type is not supported:base64Binary'. I understand the error we can't show this field as a column in document library. I have been googling around for last few days and can't find a concrete fix to the problem - some recommendations are code behind, using web service and qRules(third party) etc but have not found a proper walk through.

I will greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: You can't have Base64Binary as a promoted property. You'll need some code to upload the file to the Document Library instead of as an attachment control. This might help you out a bit --> 
http://www.bizsupportonline.net/blog/2010/04/top-10-questions-infopath-file-attachments/

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to use file attachment control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25078570/how-to-use-file-attachment-control)